# dynamically adding label

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I need some guidance. I am parsing an XML and get the members name from it. The name should be displayed on label . Now I am confused due to arbitrary number of members name. How can I put labels according to number of member's name.

Example : if I get 5 names then 5 label should be displayed with name .

any good programming guidance ?

I have a scrollview and already added a UIVew as a subview to display some static label. now name's label should be displayed on UIView.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (NSInteger i = 0, y = 50; i < [memberNameArray count]; i++, y += 30) {
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 100, 25)];
    nameLabel.text = [memberNameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [myScollView addSubview:nameLabel];
    [nameLabel release];
}
```

Assuming memberNameArray is the array of NSString which contains the names to display. And also you need to change the `x, y, width, height` values of the frame and `y += 30` based on the position of the labels in scroll view.

Answer (score 2):

The below code could  be used as reference for getting number of label depending on Array values..

Set the correct frame for each UILabel...

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i  < [myArrayOfValue count]; i++)
    {
        UILabel* myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myX,(myY + i*myHeight),myWidth,myHeight);
        myLabel.text = [myArrayOfValue objectAtIndex:i];

        ...........
        ............
        [myView addSubview:myLabel];
         myLabel.tag = i ;
        [myLabel release];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`UILabel *lblname=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,height,width)];

        [lblname setText:@"any text"];

        [lblname setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [lblname setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

        [lblname setNumberOfLines:2];

        [lblname setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

        [self.view addSubview:lblname];`

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

for(int i = 0 ; i  < [myArrayOfValue count]; i++)
    {
        UILabel* myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myX,(myY + i*myHeight),myWidth,myHeight);
        myLabel.text = [myArrayOfValue objectAtIndex:i];

```
    ...........
    ............
    [myView addSubview:myLabel];
     myLabel.tag = i ;
    [myLabel release];
}
```